# Show Error using Tag Property C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to know on how to error using `Tag` Property? I have code in VB.Net but I do not know to convert it to C#.

Scenario: The `textbox_qty` only accepts integers. If the user types a non-numeric character, it shows `Tag` property saying `Invalid Characters`.

This is the code I used in VB.Net. I use this if the for has null fields.

```vb
Private Function ValidField(ByVal ParamArray ctl() As Object) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(ctl)
        If ctl(i).Text = "" Then
            Error_reg.SetError(ctl(i), ctl(i).tag)
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function

    If ValidField(TextBox_userName, TextBox_password, TextBox_retypePassword, TextBox_lastName, TextBox_firstName, ComboxBox_group, ComboBox_question, TextBox_answer) = False Then
    Exit Sub
```

If this code does not work? Is there another code that can show error in `Tag` Property without converting my VB.Net code to C#?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: Show us your attempt at converting the code. What issues did you run into in the process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be worthwhile to check into the [Information Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.information(v=vs.110).aspx), it has methods for validating objects. While it is a VisualBasic class, it can still be used in C# which is one of the main benefits of the .Net Framework.

In Visual Basic you do not need to add any references to your project.

If you want to use the `Information Class` in C# make sure to add a reference to *Microsoft.VisualBasic* in your project, then add `using Microsoft.VisualBasic;` to the class or module that you are adding the following code to.

You can use the `Information.IsNumeric` method to validate a numeric entry.

Example VB.Net code...

```
Private Function ValidField(ByVal ParamArray ctl() As Object) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(ctl)
        Dim tB As TextBox = DirectCast(ctl(i),TextBox)
        If Not IsNumeric(tB.Text) Then
            Error_reg.SetError(tB, tB.Tag)
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Example C# code...

```
private bool ValidField(params object[] ctl)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= Information.UBound(ctl); i++) {
        TextBox tB = (TextBox)ctl[i];
        if (!Information.IsNumeric(tB.Text)) {
            Error_reg.SetError(tB, tB.Tag);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Also the `Exit Function` after the Return statement is not needed, Return automatically exits the function with the result.

Comment: Sir! @fütemire i got an error says, `Information does not in current context`. What namespace should I use?

Comment: Thank you Sir @fütemire. Don't say sorry, I don't think I deserve your sorry.

Comment: Sir! @@fütemire I got an error. 
`if (!Information.IsNumeric(ctl(i).Text))
                {
                    Error_Null.SetError(ctl(i), ctl(i).tag);
                    return false;
                }`
All `ctl` has errors and It says, `Method name expected`

Comment: Sir @fütemire ! I got another error in `Text` and `tag`. It says, `'object does not contain a definition for 'Text''` same also as `tag`. I edit my question too. I think my VB.Net code is outdated code format on checking error :D Thank you sir for always answering my question :D

Comment: The answer was not meant to be a direct copy n paste, you'll need to make it work for your application. I didn't have your error checking or controls to pass into the method so I just wrote a quick example on how to use the `Information Class` for validation purposes. I could provide you with the sample C# project I created that works, if that would help you.

The error you are describing means you need to change the input parameter of the method from `object[]` to `TextBox[]` or cast the `ctl[i]` to a TextBox before you attempt use it. I'll modify the answer again to show the cast.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use [this](http://converter.telerik.com/) converter to convert VB code to C# or vice versa.

Second please tell us where is "textbox_qty" variable in code? Assuming that it is one of parameter to "ValidField" function like this:

```
ValidField(TextBox_userName, TextBox_password, TextBox_retypePassword, TextBox_lastName, TextBox_firstName, ComboxBox_group, ComboBox_question, TextBox_answer, textbox_qty)
```

Then solution would be to update "ValidField" as follow:

```
Private Function ValidField(ByVal ParamArray ctl() As Object) As Boolean
    For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(ctl)
        If ctl(i).Name = "textbox_qty" AndAlso Not IsNumeric(ctl(i).Text) Then
            Error_reg.SetError(ctl(i), ctl(i).tag)
            Return False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```